# Ambiguous name detected: ShowHideCtrls (On WorksheetChange event & at startup only)

Tags: excel, vba, startupscript

Each time I start my file I have an error when one of the sheets I control is modified. It looks like the sub (ShowHideCtrls) called during the Worksheet change event is duplicate (but it's not, I checked this first).
When I bypass the error (stop the WorkBookOpen process) and I try to manualy modify the sheet, the sub called during the worksheet change event works properly. It's crazy, I don't understand why I have this error at file's startup and not later when I use the file... Does someone has an idea about what's going on ?
Thanks for your help

PS : I have three other files with the exact same code an no error at startup

Screenshot:
[image]

I try to remove the sub, but in this case it's not found, this why I'm sure there's no duplicates.
I tried to import code from an other book where it works properly, same result.

Comment: I found where my mistake was... in the file I was running I update a module at startup. The problem is this sub was in this module... this is why at some point it was duplicated. I moved the sub to another module and now everthing's OK... And it did not happened to other similar workbooks because in those one I was not updating the module at startup.